# How can I make my powershell script for parsing faster?

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I have this PowerShell script to parse many text files at once (about 1 MB) that look like configuration files:

**Script:**

```powershell
$counter = ($false,0,0)
$objcounter = 0
$global:files = [ordered]@{}
$txt = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($opath)

foreach($line in $txt){
    if ($counter[2] -eq "spline"){if ($counter[1] -eq 1){$counter[1]++}else{$key=$global:files.Keys;if (-not($global:files.Contains($line))){$global:files+=[ordered]@{$line=@{path=$line;type="spline"}}};$counter = ($false,0,0)}}
    elseif ($counter[2] -eq "object"){if ($counter[1] -eq 1){$counter[1]++}else{$key=$global:files.Keys;if (-not($global:files.Contains($line))){$global:files+=[ordered]@{$line=@{path=$line;type="sceneryobject"}}};$counter = ($false,0,0)}}
    elseif ($counter[2] -eq "splineh"){if ($counter[1] -eq 1){$counter[1]++}else{$key=$global:files.Keys;if (-not($global:files.Contains($line))){$global:files+=[ordered]@{$line=@{path=$line;type="splineh"}}};$counter = ($false,0,0)}}
    elseif ($counter[2] -eq "attachedobject"){if ($counter[1] -eq 1){$counter[1]++}else{$key=$global:files.Keys;if (-not($global:files.Contains($line))){$global:files+=[ordered]@{$line=@{path=$line;type="attachedobject"}}};$counter = ($false,0,0)}}
    elseif ($counter[2] -eq "splineattachement"){if ($counter[1] -eq 1){$counter[1]++}else{$key=$global:files.Keys;if (-not($global:files.Contains($line))){$global:files+=[ordered]@{$line=@{path=$line;type="splineattachement"}}};$counter = ($false,0,0)}}

    if ($line -eq "[spline]"){
        $counter = @($true,1,"spline");$objcounter++} 
    if ($line -eq "[splineh]"){
        $counter = @($true,1,"object");$objcounter++}
    if ($line -eq "[object]"){
        $counter = @($true,1,"object");$objcounter++}
    if ($line -eq "[attachObj]"){
        $counter = @($true,1,"attachedobject");$objcounter++}
    if ($line -eq "[splineAttachement]"){
        $counter = @($true,1,"splineattachement");$objcounter++}
}
```

(I know that it isn't well-structured.)

**File:**

```txt
[spline]
0
apath\path\file3.ext
8947
8946
8992
0.0584106412565594
0.250000081976033
195.973568100565
90.0000020235813
39.99999937227
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
180.853118555128


[spline_h]
0
apath\path\file2.ext
8949
8948
9022
0.0565795901830857
0.250000202235118
202.972286028874
90.0000020235813
39.99999937227
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
183.907441598005
mirror

[spline]
0
apath\path\file.ext
8951
0
9019
0.0585327145350332
0.0999999434550936
201.971026072961
90.0000020235813
39.99999937227
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
183.47110728047
mirror
```

(and so on…)

The script works fine, but it takes very long to parse the files and after a while I get “no response” and the app crashes.

This is the output that I need:

```
$global:files = [ordered]@{path=@{path="path";type="type"}}
```

Where 'path' is the file path, like: `apath\path\file.ext` and
'type' is the mesh type, like: `spline` or `spline_h`.

What can I change to make the parsing faster?

Comment: Could you please add an example of what your desired output needs to be? For me, this is not clear..

Comment: @Theo Sure. The needed output is an [ordered].

Comment: Could you explain what the script is doing and what are it's conditions, at this point we might be able to recreate it in a more efficient way but the `if` conditions seem awfully over-complicated. I understand it's a hashtable with the `paths` of each keyword between `[..]` as Key and the values are the path and the keyword.

Comment: @Theo I'm sure you'll be able to improve over my answer by far especially on the `regex` part though there are certain points OP would need to clarify before

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how it could be improved using [`regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0) mainly and some string manipulation. Note that I'm nowhere near good with it and I'm quite sure it could be improved greatly but as is, it's working for me.

It was not clear for me what should happen whenever there are two or more types (**`[keyword]`**) with the same path (path being the `hashtable` key). Right now the code is assuming there will **not** be duplicated paths on the file.

For the `regex` explanation see: https://regex101.com/r/aN4WNR/1
**NOTE:** This only works because the paths end with `.ext`, if that was not the case, you should clarify that too.

The `regex` is expecting a multi-line string to work properly, hence you would need to use either one of these (which will also improve the efficiency of the script).

- `Get-Content -Raw`
- `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(...)`

```
$txt = Get-Content -Raw ./test.txt
$re = [regex]::Matches($txt, '(?ms)\b(?<=(\[)).*?\.ext\b')
$result = [ordered]@{}

foreach($r in $re)
{
    $parse = $r.Value -split '\r?\n'
    $type = $parse[0].Replace(']','')
    $path = $parse[-1]

    $result.Add(
        $path,
        [ordered]@{
            path = $path
            type = $type
        }
    )
}
```

**Result:**

```
PS /> $result

Name                           Value
----                           -----
apath\path\file3.ext           {path, type}
apath\path\file2.ext           {path, type}
apath\path\file.ext            {path, type}

PS /> $result['apath\path\file2.ext']

Name                           Value
----                           -----
path                           apath\path\file2.ext
type                           spline_h
```

Comment: @jjb well then, if your script performs so fast why ask the question to begin with?

Comment: The problem is that I have about 50 or more files that need to be parsed, and for each file, 2 minutes is a very long time. EDIT: I have checked the speed a second time and your script needs 30 seconds longer than mine. My last comment was false because I've checked the script with `Get-Content -Raw` and that gave me no output...